# Python sqlite3 select min values from group with exceptions

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using `sqlite3` in python to retrieve data from an sqlite table called `"Documents"` with fields `"Title,Date,Author"`. For each unique title (group), I want to select the minimum `Date` and the `Author` for that date, unless the author's name is `'foo'`, in which case I would like to select the *next earliest author* that is not `'foo'`, but *retain the earliest date*. If all authors are `'foo'`, in that case it's fine.

My previous query was `"SELECT Title,min(Date),Author FROM Documents GROUP BY Title"`, which does not meet the last specification because it just chose the author for the min date, regardless of whether it was `'foo'` or not.

I was thinking of creating an aggregate function with create_aggregate and just filter out `'foo'` but I'm not sure how to ensure that I get the next earliest author. It also might be easier with a subquery or a CASE expression, but I'm not too familiar with these.

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using two queries and Python to do the job, this would work as expected:

```
# first query to get the min date of each "Title"
query = "SELECT Title, MIN(Date) FROM Documents GROUP BY Title"
min_date_by_title = cursor.fetchall(query)

# then get the author for each "Title", except if it's "foo"
query = "SELECT Title, Author FROM Documents WHERE Author != 'foo' ORDER BY Date GROUP BY Title"
author_by_title = cusor.fetchall(query)

# last step: match entries one by one of the two previous results
final_result = []
for title1, date in min_date_by_title:
    for title2, author in author_by_title:
        if title1 == title2:  # same title
            final_result.append([title1, date, author])
            break
    else:  # if we didn't find any match, it means that the only author for this title was 'foo'
        final_result.append([title1, date, 'foo'])
```

The performances can be improved by using dictionaries (keys being the different titles) to avoid the inner loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With python, I could also find the author by doing a single for loop to iterate through min_date_by_title and `SELECT Author,min(Date) WHERE Title = [current title]  and Author != 'foo'`, and do the same unconstrained by author if that yields nothing, which might be faster. I was sorta wondering if there was a way to do it directly with the sqlite query though as that tends to save time/improve performance.

Comment: @therockmandolinist I'm pretty sure doing a query for each title would be more consuming than doing only two queries whatever the number of titles to fetch, even if it implies an inner loop. Although, there might be some way to do what you want within a single query, but this would probably lead to a rather complicated query, which would not be nice for code maintainability.

Comment: for very large amounts of data though, doesn't that mean you have to loop through a bunch of unnecessary entries ever outer loop? From what I've seen, doing a query can be really really fast, so I was thinking it might be faster than an inner loop esp. with a greater number of titles - but my experience is very limited, so you might be right. And I agree about the complicated query, but performance-wise it's probably still preferable.

Comment: It depends mostly on the time it takes to contact the database. If it is hosted locally, it might be quicker indeed. The best way to know is to benchmark both solutions!